# Replace values with value from another dataframe

Tags: r, join, dplyr, na, coalesce

I have a dataset with all the sales of 2018 and trying to do a pareto analysis. The data is supposed to have a product category and most of them have but 1/5th doesn't. Now I want to fill this NA values with the product category from another dataframe but I fail with that.

Simplified example down below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1010", "1020", "1030", "1030", "1000"),
                  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "F", "G"),
                  group_ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(IDx = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000"),
                  group_ID = c("blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1[is.na(df1)] <- "None"

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "IDx")) %>% 
  mutate(group_ID = coalesce(group_ID.y, group_ID.x)) %>% 
  select(-group_ID.x, -group_ID.y)
```

The result of this code is the following dataframe:

```
     ID name group_ID
1  1000    A blankets
2  1000    A blankets
3  1000    A blankets
4  1000    A blankets
5  1000    A blankets
6  1000    A blankets
7  1000    A blankets
8  1000    A blankets
9  1000    A blankets
10 1000    B blankets
11 1000    B blankets
12 1000    B blankets
13 1000    B blankets
14 1000    B blankets
15 1000    B blankets
16 1000    B blankets
17 1000    B blankets
18 1000    B blankets
19 1000    C blankets
20 1000    C blankets
21 1000    C blankets
22 1000    C blankets
23 1000    C blankets
24 1000    C blankets
25 1000    C blankets
26 1000    C blankets
27 1000    C blankets
28 1000    D blankets
29 1000    D blankets
30 1000    D blankets
31 1000    D blankets
32 1000    D blankets
33 1000    D blankets
34 1000    D blankets
35 1000    D blankets
36 1000    D blankets
37 1010    A     None
38 1020    A     None
39 1030    B     None
40 1030    F     None
41 1000    G blankets
42 1000    G blankets
43 1000    G blankets
44 1000    G blankets
45 1000    G blankets
46 1000    G blankets
47 1000    G blankets
48 1000    G blankets
49 1000    G blankets
```

I do not want this. I want something like:

```
    ID name group_ID
1 1000    A blankets
2 1000    B blankets
3 1000    C blankets
4 1000    D blankets
5 1010    A     None
6 1020    A     None
7 1030    B     None
8 1030    F     None
9 1000    G blankets
```

I tried multiple joins and looked around on the internet but I can not fix my problem.

Hope you can help!

Comment: You can try something like `df1 %>%
 left_join(df2 %>%
            distinct(IDx, .keep_all = TRUE), by = c("ID" = "IDx")) %>%
 select(-group_ID.x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `unique(df1)` maybe works.

Answer (score 0):

data.table solution

**sample data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1010", "1020", "1030", "1030", "1000"),
name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "F", "G"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I left out the group_id column... you'll create that one with the join.

```
df2 <- data.frame(IDx = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000"),
                  group_ID = c("blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets", "blankets"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), group_ID := i.group_ID, on = .(ID = IDx)][]
```

I used `setDT()` to create data.tables out of the data.frames df1 and df2. The rest is 'simple' left join by reference.

**output**

```
#      ID name group_ID
# 1: 1000    A blankets
# 2: 1000    B blankets
# 3: 1000    C blankets
# 4: 1000    D blankets
# 5: 1010    A     <NA>
# 6: 1020    A     <NA>
# 7: 1030    B     <NA>
# 8: 1030    F     <NA>
# 9: 1000    G blankets
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()`. This is the full code:

```
distinct(
     df1 %>% 
         left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "IDx")) %>% 
         mutate(group_ID = coalesce(group_ID.y, group_ID.x)) %>% 
         select(-group_ID.x, -group_ID.y))
```